# Strange float division result

Tags: java, grails, groovy, floating-point

I have occurred in this strange division error in a grails project (But I think grails has little to do with it, is a groovy or java question I think):

If in the groovy console I run this

```
float money = -1.30
float r = 0.01

println ((money/r).class.name)
println ((money/r).floatValue())
println ((money/r).toString() )
```

I get this output

```
java.lang.Double
-130.0
-129.99999813735482
```

The float division in groovy give me a Double, and this is correct but
why the Double toString() give me a so strange value "-129.99999813735482" and
not the correct "-130.0"?

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may interest you

Comment: Floats and doubles are inaccurate to some degree. So my guess is, that the `-130.0` is an approximation of some sort and `-129.99999813735482` ist the actual value.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: generally and if at all possible, it should be declared as a decimal type such as BigDecimal in Java.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt  *"it (money) should be declared as a decimal type such as BigDecimal in Java."*  Thanks for the heads-up.  I'd thought 'non-floating point', but had not thought much further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone says, `double` and `float` aren't precise enough for what you're trying to do.

One solution is to not use `float` as your object type, and do:

```
def money = -1.30
def r = 0.01

println ((money/r).class.name)
println ((money/r).floatValue())
println ((money/r).toString() )
```

As you can see, [Groovy uses `BigDecimal`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math), which means the output is:

```
java.math.BigDecimal
-130.0
-130
```

Comment: The assertion that `double` and `float` are not precise enough is interesting. How many bits would `double` need to have in order to get the exact result correctly?

Comment: Infinitely many; `0.01` cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating-point number.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Specifically, neither 1.3 nor 0.01 can be accurately represented by a `float`.

Comment: Yes, and even though `System.out.println(1.3f)` shows `"1.3"`, you can reveal the truth with `String.format("%.16f", 1.3f)`: `"1,2999999523162842"` and see it was never `1.3` at all.

Answer (score 1):

By doing the `floatValue`, you are limiting the precission of the value. So the JVM does a rounding and you get the different value.

And before you say "but 130.0 should be the value calculated because it is the correct one" keep in mind that the computer uses binary format to represent decimal numbers and this causes rounding errors with fractions (try to represent 0.3 in binary to understand why).

Comment: The value is already inaccurate prior to calling floatValue(): that just makes it worse.